# Is the card "Outshine Them All" from the MLP CCG useless?

Tags: my-little-pony-ccg

In the MLP CCG there is a card from the Twilight / Applejack theme deck called "Outshine Them All": [http://mlpccg.wikia.com/wiki/Outshine_Them_All_(Premiere)](http://mlpccg.wikia.com/wiki/Outshine_Them_All_%28Premiere%29)

You have to pay one action token to use it, and it only gives you any action token profit if there's a troublemaker in play.

Is it useless?

(Also, if you feel like giving an opinion: 
Should it give you two action tokens for winning a faceoff? 
Or should it be one point (vs action token) for winning a faceoff?)

I'm mainly interested in whether or not it's useless and why/why not.
Perhaps even a reason it could even be useful if it's not useless.

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? In the context of Magic the Gathering, I have usually heard the word used to mean "over-powered", but that does not seem to be your meaning here.

Comment: I know nothing about the game, but it looks like the intent of the card is you spend a resource now, and potentially get multiple resources in return (since you can accomplish the gain 1 resource effect multiple times).

Comment: Yeah, I'm voting to put this on hold as unclear - please define what you mean by 'broken'. Overpowered? Nonfunctional? Absolutely terrible? Something else?

Comment: Edited the question. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: I think it's better now, but I would suggest removing the entire third paragraph. We're not really equipped to answer questions like "What *should* this card do?" That will really be completely opinion based. And it's also kind of like asking "Should this card actually be another card instead?" which doesn't really make sense as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it!

There's a problem called "Monitor EVERYTHING!" and it reduces the cost of Report Resources by one. "Outshine Them All", being a Report Resource and with  only 1 cost, can be played at this problem for free.

Also, the new Crystal Games set has multiple cards that start faceoffs at problems, which I imagine also works for this card.

(I hope it's alright to check my own answer as correct?)

Comment: Accepting your own answer is 100% okay and an intended feature of the system. It'll be voted on like any other answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it is useless, although it doesn't seem particularly useful. You may pay an action token now to receive possibly several action tokens in the future (by defeating several troublemakers at the problem and possibly again when you are in a problem faceoff at the problem). As a strategy, this is troublesome because of the opportunity costs of using the action token in the first place, the uncertainty of winning the final problem faceoff, and the fact that your opponent may not play multiple troublemakers at the problem to avoid giving you additional bonuses.

Here is the scenario where I would be inclined to play this card: It's the main phase and I now have what I consider to be an acceptable power at the troublemaker to win the faceoff next turn. I have a remaining action token after playing all of the other cards I wanted this turn. I can spend that action token now and I can expect to get it back during the troublemaker faceoff next turn. After that, I will have the opportunity to continue to collect additional action tokens for wins at the problem.

As for your second question, winning a faceoff with the card at a problem will earn you one action token plus the normal amount of bonus points.

Answer (score 1):

I've played a grand total of one game of this, so this is not a particularly definitive answer, but I'd say that it is situational and would require a particular kind of deck to support it. It's all a question of whether one Action *now* is worth potentially many Actions *later*, and whether you expect to be facing multiple Troublemakers at that problem. Of course you don't know how many Troublemakers your opponent will try to throw at you, so either it's a problem that you want to be facing often, or it's a problem where you're going to play your own Villain and then defeat them.